# How to expand a list in R

Tags: r, dataframe, list

I am trying to change a list into a dataframe. Each element of the list may have an unequal length of values. An example list is given here:

```r
a = c(1:9)
b = c(10:14)
test_list = list(a, b)
print(test_list)

#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 10 11 12 13 14
```

And the desired result is given here:

```r
desired_result = data.frame(var1 = c(rep(1,9), rep(2,5)),
                            var2 = c(1:14))
print(desired_result)

#>    var1 var2
#> 1     1    1
#> 2     1    2
#> 3     1    3
#> 4     1    4
#> 5     1    5
#> 6     1    6
#> 7     1    7
#> 8     1    8
#> 9     1    9
#> 10    2   10
#> 11    2   11
#> 12    2   12
#> 13    2   13
#> 14    2   14
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Edit: Ah apologies I misunderstood, you're looking to stack the elements on top of each other. Darren's answer is the one then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give names to the list and then `stack()`:

```r
stack(setNames(test_list, seq_along(test_list)))[2:1]

#    ind values
# 1    1      1
# 2    1      2
# 3    1      3
# 4    1      4
# 5    1      5
# 6    1      6
# 7    1      7
# 8    1      8
# 9    1      9
# 10   2     10
# 11   2     11
# 12   2     12
# 13   2     13
# 14   2     14
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data.frame(
  var1 = rep(seq_along(test_list), lengths(test_list)),
  var2 = unlist(test_list)
)


#    var1 var2
# 1     1    1
# 2     1    2
# 3     1    3
# 4     1    4
# 5     1    5
# 6     1    6
# 7     1    7
# 8     1    8
# 9     1    9
# 10    2   10
# 11    2   11
# 12    2   12
# 13    2   13
# 14    2   14
```

Comment: consider `rep(seq_along(test_list), ...)`

Comment: @Onyambu thx, that's much cleaner

Answer (score 2):

in tidyverse:

```
unnest(enframe(test_list), value)

# A tibble: 14 × 2
    name value
   <int> <int>
 1     1     1
 2     1     2
 3     1     3
 4     1     4
 5     1     5
 6     1     6
 7     1     7
 8     1     8
 9     1     9
10     2    10
11     2    11
12     2    12
13     2    13
14     2    14
```

Answer (score 1):

`lapply()` and `enframe()` turn each list entry into a `data.frame`. `bind_rows()` then combines it. With `select()` we can drop the `name` column `enframe()` created and rename `value` to `var2`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

test_list |> 
  lapply(enframe) |> 
  bind_rows(.id = "var1") |> 
  select(-name, var1, var2 = value)
#> # A tibble: 14 × 2
#>    var1   var2
#>    <chr> <int>
#>  1 1         1
#>  2 1         2
#>  3 1         3
#>  4 1         4
#>  5 1         5
#>  6 1         6
#>  7 1         7
#>  8 1         8
#>  9 1         9
#> 10 2        10
#> 11 2        11
#> 12 2        12
#> 13 2        13
#> 14 2        14
```

Comment: This can be simplified to `test_list |> map_dfr(~ tibble(var2 = .x), .id = "var1")`